# Can we use U-Boot to boot the Linux for x86-64 system?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64, bootloader, u-boot

Is it possible to boot Linux kernel using U-Boot in x86-64 machine?

Answer (score 3):

Linux can boot directly from a variety of firmware implementations including U-Boot. As for loading an OS, U-Boot supports directly booting a 32-bit or 64-bit Linux kernel as part of a FIT image. It also supports a compressed zImage.

Check the links [here](https://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot/X86) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/723112/is-it-possible-to-boot-linux-on-a-x86-machine-with-u-boot)

Comment: Running Linux directly as a FIT entry is a cool feature. I believe it is more useful for embedded systems than for the general ones as it would require reflashing/updating the firmware at every kernel update.

Comment: The FIT image can live on a filesystem just fine and is not embedded within U-Boot, so there is no reflash required for kernel updates.

Comment: And there is even x86 hardware that has U-Boot out-of-the-box.

Comment: @TomRini Oh, I thought UBoot was more of  a firmware than a bootload but for x86 it is just a bootloader. Then yes, FIT is just a wrongly chosen name for yet-another-boot-format. FIT has a specific meaning on Intel's CPUs and the ability to read a FIT image, for a bootloader, is nothing special afterall.

Comment: @MargaretBloom sorry, I think you're still missing something.  U-Boot is (as much as anything else, due to needing to use Intel's FSP/similar packages, and that's a universal thing) firmware on x86 as coreboot or AMI's UEFI.  Just like how GRUB or a Linux kernel with EFI stub is loaded from a filesystem, U-Boot can do that too.  And yes, a FIT image is a container format that provides various useful features.

Comment: @TomRini U-Boot is both a firmware (init the HW) and a bootloader (load an OS) AFAIK. The FIT, as used in Intel terminology, is a table stored in the Flash ROM and that provides various "images" for the CPU to execute. The FIT is mandatory since Haswell and only after it has been processed that the CPU jumps to the reset vector and this is where U-Boot comes into play (the firmware part of it, that uses the FSP). When the initialization is done, U-Boot (the booloader part) will follow either the UEFI or legacy boot rules. Only here, we find the ...

Comment: @TomRini ... "FIT Image" as described in this answer and which is barely related to the "real" FIT. I though U-Boot was able to load a Linux kernel directly from the "real" FIT, avoiding the need to load it from a FS.

Comment: @MargaretBloom sorry, I misread one of your earlier messages.  Yes, as U-Boot is a real firmware it can be part of the Intel-FIT-image and performs everything a regular firmware would and lives on flash.  Sorry for the confusion.